# Search box ability

Tags: search, ee3

I am new to EE. However, is it possible to create a search ability on a site without the need of an add-on? If not, what add-ons are good for creating a EE search ability for the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EE comes with search capabilities out of the box.  https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/search/index.html

You'll need to make sure your channel fields are set as searchable, other than that the link above gives a few code examples.

Edit: If the default search doesn't do it for you then two big search add-ons are [Low Search](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search) and [Super Search](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search)